# Python find the index of an item in a list where some columns are not important

Tags: python, list

I have a list in python which is like the following example:
`a = [[1,2,'aaa'] , [3,4,'nnnn']`

How can I get the index of [1,2,'aaa'] by just saying [1,2, *] in which * means not important? In other words, I want to get the indexes of the items where their first column is 1 and their second column is 2 and the third column value is not important.

Comment: A simple `loop` over all items of the list will do. Return the first occurance where a[i][0] is `1` and a[i][1] is `2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
a = [[1, 2, 'aaa'], [3, 4, 'nnnn']]

indices = [i for i, (first, second, *_) in enumerate(a) if (first, second) == (1, 2)]
print(indices)
```

**Output**

```
[0]
```

Comment: It would require one more condition to check for the strings

Comment: @Bazingaa care to explain?

Comment: @DanielMesejo: "and the third column value is not important.". So I am assuming there is some third list where the strings which are not important are stored. So not just 1,2 but also the third value should match with some pre defined list

Comment: @Bazingaa I believe that the OP doesn't care about what is after.

Comment: @DanielMesejo yes, I do not care about next columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) for an extendible solution:

```
from operator import itemgetter

a = [[1,2,'aaa'] , [3,4,'nnnn']]
getter = itemgetter(0, 1)  # get first and second items
indices = [idx for idx, item in enumerate(a) if getter(item) == (1, 2)]  # [0]
```

Answer (score 0):

How a about a plain and simple loop?

```
a = [[1,2,'aaa'] , [3,4,'nnnn']
for i, item in enumerate(a):
    if item[0] == 1 and item[1] == 2:
    print(i)
    break
```